# bayesian problem using inverse gamma: negative initial values

Tags: bayesian, gamma-distribution, inverse-gamma-distribution, brms

My study involves a dependent variable measuring reading times (minimum value = 0.3) and two categorical variables (y = "quick" or "slow"; t = "cute" or "ugly") that are used to define conditions. The design is nested.

I have determined that my dependent variable fits very well into an inverse gamma distribution. However, I encountered issues with homogeneity of variances assumption and the normality of residues when running models using glmer, besides the model prediction was a bad fit. As a result, I decided to use a brm model instead.

[image]

During the process, I received a warning message that read `gamma_lpdf: Inverse scale parameter[1] is -xxx, but must be >0!`and `Initialization between (-2, 2) failed after 100 attempts.` I attempted to address the issue by setting `init=0.1`, but it did not work. Although using the `log` link instead of the `inverse` link resolved the issue, I want to use the inverse family. **Therefore, I am wondering how I can instruct the model to only use positive values during initialization.** The model prediction looks good, but I don't want to use it if it gives these warnings.

```
install.packages("VGAM")
library(VGAM)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rinvgauss(100, mean = 1.07, shape = 2.28, dispersion = 0.11), # dependent variable: reading time
                 id = rep(1:100, each = 60), # participant's id                 
                 speed_frame = rep_len(rep(c(-1, 1), each = 60), 100), # between-subjects factor
                 beauty = rep_len(c(rep(-1, 30), rep(1, 30)), 100), # within-subjects factor
                 stimuli_id =rep(1:60, times = 100))
for (i in 2:5) {
  df[, i] <- scale(df[, i], center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
}

brm(x ~ speed_frame + beauty + speed_frame:beauty + (1 + speed_frame | id) + (1 + speed_frame + beauty | stimuli_id), data=df, family=Gamma(link = "inverse"), backend = "cmdstanr")
```

Comment: This question is in part about fitting a model with [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html). To make it easier to get help, please provide a minimal reproducible example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This means your code and a data sample, so that the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Some comments: (a) The VGAM::rinv.gaussian function takes parameters n, mu, lambda; it's not clear how you managed with mean, shape, dispersion instead. (b) You generate different number of draws for the different variables; switch from `data.frame` to `tibble`to see the warnings. Better yet, use a package like [simstudy](https://tinyurl.com/2cfncte3) to simulate data. (c) Why do you scale the ID variables? (d) You have two categorical predictors, speed = quick/slow and beauty=cute/ugly. It doesn't make sense that you treat them as numeric and standardize them.

Comment: Fixing the above will not solve the issue however. I think the problem is that you want to use the inverse link with the random effects. Not sure how brms deals with random effects in a Gamma model but the errors seem to indicate that, at initialization, the fixed effects beta + the random effects u don't necessarily evaluate to a positive value. With the inverse link `(EY)^-1 = X*beta + Z*u`, so if `X*beta + Z*u` isn't positive, you run into trouble. Even though you don't want to, it'll be easiest to switch to the log link instead.

Comment: @Olivia Not directly what you're asking about, but your plot appears to be of the marginal distribution of the response, but the model is for the *conditional* response. You can't assess the suitability of a model for the conditional response from the raw values of the variable.

Comment: PS: Random effects are assumed to have mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2_{\text{r.e.}}$ as they represent individual-specific deviations from the fixed effects. It doesn't make sense to constrain them to be all positive.